# Why are these answers ordered strangely?

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

**Why are these answers ordered in the way they are?**

[image]

The answers to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/54666/62397) are (at the time of this post) ordered with an unaccepted answer of 79 first, followed by an accepted answer of 38.

I was under the impression that (on all Stack Exchange sites) an **accepted answer always appears first,** followed by other answers in order of decreasing score.  Why does this situation not conform to that?

Comment: How do you have your sort order?

Comment: @ElysianFields  Hmm... it is on "votes".  I've never noticed this option before.

Comment: @ElysianFields  So, if this is the case, then does the original order I mentioned not exist anymore?  None of the three tabs ("Active", "Oldest", "Votes") seem to correspond with it.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Accepted answers don't float “on top” when self-answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5486/165773)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I missed this the first time - when an OP posts a self-answer, answers are sorted by votes *even if it's accepted*.

Notice the OP in that case is actually the same user who wrote the accepted answer.